# Learning parameters of MultivariateNormalDiag in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have been trying to code up a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) in tensorflow. I was able to implement the version with has a Gaussian encoder network and a Bernoulli decoder as in the paper [Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114).

However, I would like to work with real valued data and I have not been able to get a VAE with a Gaussian decoder to work. I have narrowed this down to the problem with my network: my network does not seem to learn the parameters of the diagonal multivariate Gaussian. Here is the code for very simple test case. Where my input data is just drawn from a normal(0,1). The network needs to learn is the mean and variance of my data. I would expect the mean to converge to 0 and variance to converge to 1. But it does not:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()

input_dim = 1
hidden_dim = 10
learning_rate = 0.001
num_batches = 1000

# Network
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, input_dim))

with tf.variable_scope('Decoder'):
    h1 = tf.layers.dense(x, hidden_dim, activation=tf.nn.softplus, name='h1')
    mu = tf.layers.dense(h1, input_dim, activation=tf.nn.softplus, name='mu')
    diag_stdev = tf.layers.dense(h1, input_dim, activation=tf.nn.softplus, name='diag_stdev')

# Loss: -log(p(x))
with tf.variable_scope('Loss'):
    dist = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=diag_stdev)
    loss = - tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(1e-10 + dist.prob(x)))

# Optimizer
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./log_dir', tf.get_default_graph())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    mu_plot = np.zeros(num_batches,)
    for i in range(num_batches): # degenerate case batch_size of 1
        input_ = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[0], cov=np.diag([1]), size=(1))    
        loss_ , mu_ , diag_stdev_ , _ = sess.run([loss, mu, diag_stdev, train_step],feed_dict={x: input_})
        print("-p(x): {}, mu: {}, diag_stdev: {}".format(loss_, mu_,diag_stdev_))
```

Comment: I am also having difficulty solving the same problem, VAE with Gaussian decoder implementation

Comment: Same here. Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: Does this Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae) useful. Thanks!